# Connecting to SQS from EKS using Role ARN

Tags: .net-core, amazon-sqs, asp.net-core-2.1, amazon-eks

I am trying to connect to SQS from my .NET Core service in EKS. I am using AWSSDK.SQS NuGet package.

My DevOps team provided me the ARN of a role that has full permissions on SQS (read, write.)

After reviewing the documentation on AWS, I am not sure how to pass the RoleARN when connecting to SQS. I did find CredentialProfileOptions.RoleArn and AssumeRoleAWSCredentials but it wasn't that clear to me on how to use these.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are in need of using something like kube2iam.

In short you need to deploy kube2iam daemonset to your cluster. That will allow you to specify an annotation on your application deployment

> iam.amazonaws.com/role: your-role-arn

After you have that annotation in place you need to modify your IAM with trust relationship policy which will allow Eks worker nodes to assume that role. That way your application will be able to acquire temporary credentials of the IAM that has desired permissions.

I have actually written a full guide on installation and configuration of kube2iam in the blog post [kube2iam in full](https://medium.com/@marcincuber/amazon-eks-iam-roles-and-kube2iam-4ae5906318be)

Alternative to kube2iam is kiam which you can read about [here](https://github.com/uswitch/kiam)