# Quarkus Java application assuming node group IAM role instead of the specified pod one

Tags: java, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-iam, quarkus

I'm trying to deploy a Quarkus application *(JDK21, Quarkus 3.6.7)* inside a pod in an EKS cluster that interacts with SQS queue.

The CICD pipeline we're using injects the correct environment variables inside the pod: AWS_REGION, AWS_ROLE_ARN, AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE, AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS. I see that the AWS_ROLE_ARN has the correct ARN role value, ending with **-role-execution-platform-cnt**.

But here's the issue, when I start my Quarkus application another role is assumed by my application, a role with arn: ...-managed-nodegroup-role/..., so a different one from the one specified in the environment variable. This "nodegroup-role" doesn't have any sqs reading permission, so it just throws an error (I changed a bunch of ids and names for privacy reasons):

```
ERROR [my.pac.ada.con.QueueConsumer] (executor-thread-4) [messageDequeue ASYNC ERROR]: software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException: User: arn:aws:sts::accountId:assumed-role/test-project-managed-nodegroup-role/i-somenumbers is not authorized to perform: sqs:receivemessage on resource: arn:aws:sqs:eu-east-1:accountId:test_project_svts_sqs_create_account_event because no identity-based policy allows the sqs:receivemessage action (Service: Sqs, Status Code: 403, Request ID: requestId)
```

So, what is happening here? My project is similar to the example one used by [Quarkus to show SQS extensions](https://github.com/isaccanedo/amazon-sqs-quickstart)

Comment: you need to give [SQS access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20355413/175554) for EKS [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57542472/175554) may help